# Which exception to raise if arrived at an illegal location in code?

Tags: python, exception

My code needs to process either a file or a directory (either of them is accepted from the shell as arguments from `argparse`).

The relevant snippet is:

```
if in_dir:
    in_glob = os.path.join(in_dir, "*." + ext)
elif in_file:
    in_glob = in_file
else:
    # Should never arrive here!
    print("error: neither input file, nor input directory are set.")
    raise SystemExit
```

In the `else` stanza (which should never be entered), I'd like to raise a more informative exception than `SystemExit` - to indicate that the control-flow arrived at an illegal location.

**Which exception would you recommend I raise?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many other languages have an `assert_not_reached` function for this purpose, but python does not. It's commonly subsituted with

```
assert False, 'this should never be reached'
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use either `SystemError` or `EnvironmentError` but will be handy to use `IOError` or `LookupError` as well.